# Как объединить два одинаковых Юзера в один ? PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю выборку из бд, вывожу данные посредством `foreach`, при выводе получаю следующее:

```
Игорь (id: 1)
Баллов: 5

Ирина (id: 2)
Баллов: 2

Игорь (id: 1)
Баллов: 3

Алекс (id: 3)
Баллов: 8
```

В бд имеется таблица `my_users_score: user_id, score`, при foreach-е получаю списком user_id - идентификатор, score - балл из таблицы (my_users_score), функцией `user_info($user_id, 'name')` **получаю имена юзеров** из таблицы `my_users`. Появилось проблема с **обьединением двух одинаковых юзеров** (список вывода выше указан), как решить проблему? **Чтобы получилось:**

```
Игорь (id: 1)
Баллов: 8 (5+3)

Ирина (id: 2)
Баллов: 2

Алекс (id: 3)
Баллов: 8
```

*при выводе информации **сортирую по баллам**

Comment: Это всё делается 1 запросом. Добавьте свои запросы.

Comment: $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM my_users_score WHERE hall_id='$hall_id' AND datetime BETWEEN $now AND $end ORDER BY score DESC");
foreach ($data as $post => $key)
{
user_info($key['user_id']);
echo '<br/>';
echo $key['score'];
}

Comment: Прочитайте учебник, темы Группировка (GROUP BY) и Агрегатные функции.

Comment: @Олеся с функции user_info тоже запрос добавьте

Comment: Сделал:

SELECT t.`user_id`, t.`score`, t.`price` FROM `my_users_score` t JOIN (SELECT `user_id`, max(`price`) as `prices` FROM `my_users_score` GROUP BY `user_id`) as t1 ON t.`user_id`= t1.`user_id` AND t.`price` = t1.`prices` AND t.`price` = t1.`prices` ORDER BY quantity DESC;

не получилось достигнуть цели :(

сейчас выводит:

Игорь (id: 1)
Баллов: 5 - нет суммирования баллов

Ирина (id: 2)
Баллов: 2

Алекс (id: 3)
Баллов: 8